# Can not add Advantage.Data.Provider reference to VisualStudio 2017 C# .net project

Tags: c#, .net, advantage-database-server

according to Advantage Database manuals to add Advantage.Data.Provider reference to c# .Net project:
"In your project, Add a reference to Advantage.Data.Provider. For example, from Visual Studio .NET, choose "Add Reference…" from the Project menu. Advantage.Data.Provider should be available in the .NET component list. If it is not, you may need to run the Advantage .NET Data Provider installation."

Well, VisualStudio 2017 with last updates, Advantage .Net Data Provider v11.10 is installed. Trying to add reference, can not find Advantage.Data.Provider in project reference list. Did I miss something?

Here is screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN8lo.png)

Comment: "project reference list" are you actually looking at project references? Can you add a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `Advantage.Data.Provider.DLL` in the folder `C:\[Program Files]\Advantage X.x\ADO.NET`. You can select the file using the browse button in your screenshot.

Source: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/mergedProjects/ads_dotnet/base_ado_net_doc/installing_the_advantage_net_data_provider.htm

Comment: Well, I found it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Advantage 11.10\ado.net\1.0. Tnx!